# tesseract-ocr - To extract table

Tags: tesseract

I am new to tesseract ocr. I am making use of Google api to extract words and lines from image. I want to extract tables/horizontal & vertical lines. I tried with FindLinesCreateBlockList method. It returns BLOCK_LIST type. I am not aware how to print values from BLOCK_LIST.

Is FindLinesCreateBlockList the right method to extract tables/lines?

Comment: did u find any solution? if yes please share your code please.